# Alternativa para Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou usando Session para armazenar o objeto da empresa que o usuário está logado.

Uso também para fazer filtros, para ele visualizar apenas o que é da empresa logada.

Porém, estou com os seguinte os problemas:

1 - Se o usuário fechou a aba, o seu cookie de autenticação ainda fica na máquina, aí quando ele acessa novamente, a Session está null, ocasionando erro.

2- É uma app multi tenant, logo, se tiver 1000 usuário logados, haverá 1000 ponteiros na memória para armazenar essa Session

Comment: Eu iria direto usar o Redis.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez mesmo com multiplos usuários, em várias empresas e no mesmo banco ?

Comment: Com certeza, sem pensar muito.

Answer (score 3):

**Desaconselho totalmente o uso de Session no MVC**, principalmente em aplicações que usam Load-Balance: **Use cookies**! O Http assim como o MVC é *StateLess*.

Você não precisa nem criar ponteiros de memória nem fazer requisições no banco para descobrir quem está logado. Usando cookies você deve gravar apena o necessário para identificação do usuário logado: Nome, Id, Login, matricula, empresa, etc e criptografe estas informações antes de escrever o cookie. Encapsule tudo numa classe e a persista no cookie.

Mais rápido, seguro, menos tráfego de rede e consumo de memória e ainda é de acordo com as recomendações da própria MS, tanto que o próprio **Asp.NET Identity** usa cookies em suas autenticações e nada de Session.

Verifique como o Identity se comporta e faça igual. É bem eficaz, teste e me diga se funcionou para você.

Answer (score 2):

Eu também uso Session na minha aplicação para manter os dados de acesso do usuário. Considero ele mais rápido do que ficar buscando no banco de dados direto.

#### Questão 1

Sobre a perda da Session, acredito que você deve configurar o time-out dela para um valor maior. Altere o seu Web.config conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
  ...
```

Outra coisa que eu faço é no Global.asax.cs, vejo se a session já morreu e tem autenticação do Form, eu crio novamente a session. Exemplo abaixo:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
    {                
        HttpCookie authenticationCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authenticationCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authenticationCookie.Value);
            if (!authenticationTicket.Expired)
            {
                if (Session["usuarioLogado"] == null)
                {
                    CriaNovamenteSession(authenticationTicket.Name);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            Session["usuarioLogado"] = null;
    }
}
```

#### Questão 2

Eu ainda não testei com tantos usuários, mas acho que é melhor ter 1000 ponteiros do que toda hora acessar o banco de dados para pegar dados.

Comment: Marlon, obrigado pela resposta. Quanto ao tempo da Sessao, mesmo fechando o navegador e abrindo-o novamente, se estiver autenticado, consiguirei capturar a session? Outra coisa, referente ao seu código postado, no meu caso, ele pode estar em mais de uma Empresa, como poderia contornar? redirecionar para selecionar a empresa que quer logar?

Comment: Também pensei no uso de Cache[""]

Comment: @Rod desculpa a demora. Sobre a empresa, acho interessante sempre manter o usuário em uma empresa e fazer algo para ele trocar de empresa, faço isto no meu sistema, porém para mim "Empresa" é uma visão e "Cliente/Filial" são acessos internos. Porém isto é uma forma de implementação. Sobre a session, mesmo fechando ela fica "ativa" pois isto fica dentro do servidor e não no client.